I want to know how to scale child widgets in flutter
I applied Transform.scale, but the aspect ratio is broken and the buttons are popping out. I want to know how to scale all child widgets without breaking them.
I've tried setting the width and height on the Container, and I've tried to warp with AspectRatio on it. But it always broken when I changed the size of Chrome.
Added, edited
I want to fit the screen. Base size is 590x750.
When I changed to lower than base size, it breaks.
class TestApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestApp({super.key});

  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: TestPage(),
    );
  }
}

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestPage({super.key});

  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var width = screenSize.width;
    var height = screenSize.height;
    var scaleW = width / 590;
    var scaleH = height / 750;
    var scaleFit = scaleW < scaleH ? scaleW : scaleH;
    scaleFit *= 0.8; //scale for test
    print('$width, $height, $scaleW, $scaleH, $scaleFit');

    return Stack(
      children: [
        FilledBox(text: 'screen', color: Colors.white,),
        Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Transform.scale(
              scale: scaleFit,
              child: TestMenu(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class FilledBox extends StatelessWidget {
  const FilledBox({ super.key, required this.text, required this.color });
  final Color color;
  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) { 
        var w = constraints.maxWidth;
        var h = constraints.maxHeight;
        return Container(
          width: w,
          height: h,
          color: color,
          child: Text('$text $w,$h', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, decoration: TextDecoration.none),),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


class TestMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestMenu({super.key});

  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 590, 
      height: 750, 
      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
      child: 
      //FilledBox(color: Colors.cyan,),
      Dialog(),
    );
  }
}

class Dialog extends StatelessWidget {
  const Dialog({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        
        SizedBox(
          width: 590, 
          height: 660, 
          child: FilledBox(text: 'dialog', color: Colors.green,),
        ),
    
        SizedBox(
          width: 590, 
          height: 90, 
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
    
              IconButton(
                onPressed: (){ }, 
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero, 
                icon: SizedBox(width: 190, height: 90, child: FilledBox(text:'bt', color: Colors.blue,),),
              ),
    
              IconButton(
                onPressed: (){ }, 
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero, 
                icon: SizedBox(width: 190, height: 90, child: FilledBox(text:'bt', color: Colors.orange,),),
              ),
    
              IconButton(
                onPressed: (){ }, 
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero, 
                icon: SizedBox(width: 190, height: 90, child: FilledBox(text:'bt', color: Colors.blue,),),
              ),
    
            ],
          ),
        ),
    
      ],
    );
  }
}

Added2
If screen size is more than my setting is OK.
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/65lrOZXB.png
If screen size is less than my setting is not OK.
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/WSCi5bwX.png

Hey there. first provide your Transform.sale code then provide image of your broken item then we can help you more

I added my code.

You can easily use ScaleTransition Widget, which is provided by Flutter itself.
Check this out to get to know scaleTransition

I think ScaleTrantion is same Transform.scale.
I want to fit the screen.

Why don't u try sale:1?  use scaleTrantion and when u want to set it to full-screen set the scale to 1

I am converting my app to flutter for practice. I want to keep old UI. I used scaling for supporting many screen size.

I found the OverflowBox.
I wrapped the widget with Overflowbox. And my problem was solved.
class TestMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestMenu({super.key});

  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OverflowBox(
      maxWidth: 590,
      maxHeight: 750,
      child: Container(
        width: 590, height: 750, 
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
        child: Dialog(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I think I asked the wrong question.
Because it was a screen size and overflow issue, not a scale issue.
